# Trying to run an ansible playbook through from a remote api call

Tags: python, ansible

I have an API that I built that takes system configuration parameters as playbook variables and builds playbooks on the fly and attempts to run them.  I can hit my API but Ansible throws the following error when invoked via

```
Options = namedtuple('Options', ['connection', 'module_path', 'forks', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'check', 'diff', 'listhosts', 'listtasks', 'listtags', 'syntax'])
loader = DataLoader()
options = Options(connection='local', module_path='%s/' % (ROOT_DIR), forks=100, become=None, become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False,
                diff=False, listhosts=False, listtasks=False, listtags=False, syntax=False)
passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=[inventory_path])
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
executor = PlaybookExecutor(  
            playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader,  
            options=options, passwords=passwords)  
results = executor.run()
```

Here is the error:

> fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"`echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1527184628.45-99532072739462`\" && echo ansible-tmp-1527184628.45-99532072739462=\"`echo /tmp/ansible/ansible-tmp-1527184628.45-99532072739462`\" ), exited with result 127", "unreachable": true}

The playbook is run on localhost and my connection parameter is set to local as well so i am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: So the web service is Flask based and being served up via gunicorn wsgi.   However it works just find using the Flask app runner.

Answer (score 3):

Check your permissions under `/tmp/ansible`. The best option is configuring your `ansible.cfg` to point to:

```
remote_tmp     = /tmp/.ansible-${USER}/tmp
```

> From [davesnigier.com](https://davesnigier.com/changing-ansible-temporary-directory/) and [github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5725)

Comment: The permissions are fine.  It's like when Ansible forks to run the playbook it is not able to write to /tmp

Comment: I ended up ditching Ansible and going with a strictly boto3 solution.

Comment: That fixed it for the exact same problem on my end. However, I didn't change the config. I just changed the permissions on the remote host in /home/ansible-web/.ansible/tmp. Whoever it was that set ansible up before I got here messed it up. All fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Ubuntu 20.04.

Here is a workaround for it

mv /usr/bin/sleep /usr/bin/sleep.dist

ln -s /bin/true /usr/bin/sleep

This disables sleep on ubuntu and replaces it with a symlink to "true".  This allows it to always return.  The link where I found this when I had this issue is below.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2275812-ubuntu-wsl-ansible-permission-error-when-running-localhost-playbook

Comment: Can you explain it in your answer instead of referring to a link?

Comment: The odd thing is that this error seems inconsistent with one instance of WSL Ubuntu 20.04 vs another. Many thanks for sharing this solution.